# Is Arara safe/secure

Tags: shell-escape, security, arara

I have just begun playing around with [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/arara) and I am curious if there are safety/security concerns. For example, `pdflatex` from TeX Live has shell escape disabled by default. If the TeX Live team think that shell escape is too dangerous (and I am not sure that is the reason it has been disabled) to be enabled by default, then I am not sure it is wise to give `arara` so much power. Is there a way to rein in the power of `arara`?

One concern I have is that it might be possible to inject a malicious `arara` directives into a package or the `aux` file.

I am not so concerned about shell escape, but rather other things that can be done. For example, can an untrusted package use the file contents environment to overwrite the `pdflatex` rule on the first pass such that on the second pass custom code is run?

Comment: arara will enable the shell escape only if the directive requires it: `arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}`. Since you are writing the directives, there will be no surprise.

Comment: @egreg but if I compile someone else's document I would need to inspect all the directives. It is also not clear to me if directives can be hidden such that they are not human readable.

Comment: I don't think your concerns have anything to do with arara: it will obey only to directives in the main file and not those possibly found in input files. Those in the main file *must* be in the form `% arara: ...` so they are easily searchable.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Do you know anyone ever to had a virus via a LaTeX or related file? I know the possibility is there, but I am curious why the concern. As to arara 900% guaranteed.

Comment: Also note that you have to have the directives installed, so they can't be entirely arbitrary. If you have one allowing `-shell-escape` and you are paranoid you'll presumably not run it anyway. (If you are that paranoid you probably won't run `arara` or any other automation tool anyway.)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides we get occasional messages about viruses on ctan.  100% of those i've seen have been spurious (due to clunky old virus checkers) -- for some reason people think it's better to complain to us than to apply common sense to the alert.

Comment: @wasteofspace Thanks. If I was a virus author, targeting CTAN and LaTeX is a guarantee that the virus would not spread far. It can only spread to a small ecosystem of users in a well supported community and it will just fizzle and die out. This whole paranoia started with one security employee writing an article as to how TeX/LaTeX could be used to plant a virus. No brainer really. A more plausible scenario is that a disgruntled phd slave would mess-up a couple of declarations in files and annoy a lot of academics in his department.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides, the example those researchers gave using the `bibtex` format was rather interesting. Interestingly enough it let to a tightening of the MikTeX security, AFAIR it now use something like what TL had been doing for years.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<sub>I think my answer will be totally biased, but here it goes. `:)`</sub>

It's quite subjective for me to afirm that `arara` is safe or secure. It's just a program with a specific purpose, just like most of the tools available out there. Maybe the best answer I can come up with is: it depends.

`arara` per se simply expands directives into commands through rules that specify the way this expansion shoud happen. Commands are then delegated to the underlying operating system.

The program requires a valid directive (mapped to a rule) in order to run, otherwise the process stops.

```
Uh-oh, I could not find the 'foo' rule in the search path. Could
you take a look if the rule name is correct and if the rule is
accessible through the search path?
```

If there are no directives, `arara` will also complain.

```
I didn't find any directives in 'test.tex', and so didn't do
anything. Is that what you really wanted?
```

If we run `arara` with the `--log` option enabled, we can have a list of directives found in the `.tex` file.

```
21 Mar 2013 07:32:10.630 INFO  Arara - Welcome to arara!
21 Mar 2013 07:32:10.634 INFO  Arara - Processing file 'folheto.tex', please wait.
21 Mar 2013 07:32:10.635 INFO  DirectiveExtractor - Reading directives from folheto.tex.
21 Mar 2013 07:32:10.649 TRACE DirectiveExtractor - Directive found in line 1 with pdflatex.
21 Mar 2013 07:32:10.650 TRACE DirectiveExtractor - Directive found in line 2 with clean: { files: [ folheto.aux, folheto.log, folheto.sxc, folheto.synctex.gz ] }.
...
```

Heiko suggested a `--dry-run` option to `arara`, which consists of simulating the execution without actually running the commands. Hopefully it will be available in the upcoming version.

After getting the directives, `arara` will look for rules.

```
...
21 Mar 2013 07:32:10.799 INFO  TaskDeployer - Deploying tasks into commands.
21 Mar 2013 07:32:10.799 TRACE TaskDeployer - Task 'pdflatex' found in '/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules'.
21 Mar 2013 07:32:11.010 TRACE TaskDeployer - Task 'clean' found in '/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules'.
21 Mar 2013 07:32:11.083 TRACE TaskDeployer - Task 'clean' found in '/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules'.
21 Mar 2013 07:32:11.099 TRACE TaskDeployer - Task 'clean' found in '/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules'.
21 Mar 2013 07:32:11.104 TRACE TaskDeployer - Task 'clean' found in '/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules'.
...
```

`arara` shows the full path for the rule according to the directive. Then the commands will be executed.

```
...
21 Mar 2013 07:32:11.108 INFO  CommandTrigger - Ready to run commands.
21 Mar 2013 07:32:11.108 INFO  CommandTrigger - Running 'PDFLaTeX'.
21 Mar 2013 07:32:11.108 TRACE CommandTrigger - Command: pdflatex "folheto.tex"
...
```

Back to the question. Is it possible to run malicious code through `arara`? Yes. Is this a problem? No. `:)` After all, we can get, say, a Perl program and deliberately inject code into its execution. Or write a `.tex` file with malicious Lua code inside it. Or have a naughty Makefile that runs `rm -rf /` in our system.

I think the security issues are valid. Let's see an example, the `clean` rule.

```
!config
# Clean rule for arara
# author: Paulo Cereda
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: clean
name: CleaningTool
command: <arara> @{remove}
arguments:
- identifier: remove
  default: <arara> @{isFalse(file == getOriginalFile(), isWindows("cmd /c del", "rm -f").concat(' "').concat(file).concat('"'))}
```

Using this directive

```
% arara: clean: { files: [ foo.aux, foo.log ] }
```

will make `arara` remove two files, `foo.aux` and `foo.log`. There's an important check which prevents `arara` from removing the main `.tex` file if no `files` directive argument is provided. Say,

```
% arara: clean
```

does nothing.

Let's say we will replace the `default` instruction by

```
default: <arara> @{isWindows("cmd /c del", "rm -f").concat(' "').concat(file).concat('"')}
```

If we try

```
% arara: clean
```

the main `.tex` file (possibly `foo.tex`) will be gone! Neat isn't it? `:)`

Of course, we are talking about a faulty rule.

`arara` has the following workflow:

1. Read all directives.
2. Find their corresponding rules.
3. Expand directives into commands.
4. Run all commands.

That's the basic idea behind the program.

It might be worth mentioning that the program makes use of a library to execute these external commands which doesn't allow subshell calls.

Anyway, I really don't know what else to say. `:)` We are all vulnerable to malicious packages, but that's a risk we need to take. Thankfully, source code has to be available in order to hit CTAN (not entirely true, but true for packages), so we can always check entries for suspicious elements.

As I said, LuaTeX for example allows I/O from Lua, which can also be dangerous. We are exposed to some level of threat at some time, it depends our use. `:)`

And running `arara` (or any program) in a server without a sandbox... ouch. `:)`

Comment: Great description! And very useful tool :)

Answer (score 22):

`shell escape` will enable `pdflatex` to save, write, delete and call another program from the system. Some times this can be dangerous as malicious code may be called and executed, endangering the system.

Arara, on the other hand, executes the directives, written by the user, inside the documents. Without a directive, nothing is executed. These directives, written by more of a *lovely human* (`;-)`, are more human readable. For example if the directive says `arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}`, then it is a YES to `shell escape` and NO otherwise.

In a nutshell,

1. If you have a directive to use `shell escape`, only then it will be used.
2. These directives are found at the top of your source and are easily readable. If you didn't write those directives,  you can easily disable the option by putting a `no` and be safe and happy.
3. An added advantage of using arara is that you can selectively enable `shell escape` to a particular document.

Hence, I feel that using arara is safe noting that the author is a good friend of mine `;-)`.

Comment: Ad 2.: The directives can be anywhere in the source file.

Comment: …  but you can easily search for the string “arara”.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Arara works even if they are found after the `\end{document}` (I don't like that part). But as Speravir notes, they are easily searchable. `:-)`

Comment: I believe this answer to be very optimistic unfortunately. From a quick look at `arara`'s doc, it seems that if someone is able to upload a custom rule to `$ARARA_HOME/rules`, he can basically run any code through `arara`... Therefore, I wouldn't dare installing `arara` on a server. And if I did anyway, I certainly wouldn't dare resorting to  `arara` on said server to process documents automatically, due to the `shell escape` possibility!

Comment: @Xavier: If a random user is allowed to copy a `yaml` rule into the programs folder of a server, then probably he wouldn't do it. He will directly attack the server and users `;-)`

Comment: @HarishKumar True, but it is still a possible escalation. And the 2nd point is definitely a no-go, so I don't see why I would install `arara` if I can't guarantee it will run securely automatically.

Comment: On the `-shell-escape` question, the obvious solution is to have local `.yaml` files on a server which don't allow this option.

Comment: @HarishKumar I think you should be able to write a pattern for the config file that would prevent directives after `\end{document}`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub: My thought too. But it is not my case...

Answer (score 5):

In general, I think of `pdflatex` as being pretty safe since it can really only read and write files. I understand TeX is Turing complete and you can make it make toast, but I think it would take a lot of work to do something malicious. On the other hand, `arara` has full access to the command line and I think with relatively little work can be made to do bad things. The type of security hole I was thinking about can be seen with the following example that doesn't fully work

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{pdflatex.yaml}
!config
identifier: pdflatex
name: pdflatex
command: touch temp.txt
arguments:
- identifier: target
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.target}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

The idea is that the `filecontents` environment is used to overwrite the `arara` `pdflatex` rule to do something malicious. To be malicious you would need to replace the benign `touch temp.txt` and obfuscate the `filecontents`, but neither of those should be too hard.

The idea behind the attack only works if `tex` can write to the `arara` rules directory. I think this is a major limitation, since I believe there are pretty strong constraints on where `pdflatex` can write. That said, my intended use of `arara` was for the current directory to be added to the `arara` rules path.

The reason that the attack doesn't fully work is that the second `arara` `pdflatex` directive does not invoke the new `pdflatex` rule which has been written by the `filecontents` environment, but rather uses the original rule. The attack is still successful in the the overloaded rule is written and the next time `arara` is run the malicious rule is used. This behavior is somewhat surprising to me and I am not sure it is intended. Nevertheless, it is useful as a security precaution.

Comment: I'm nowhere close to imply that Windoze is safe but I can't even update my MikTeX without passing two/three UAC checks so it needs to be fooling user into doing something. And if that is the case then nothing is safe anyway e.g. with the properly hidden keylogger, it can mail the user your IP and pass without doing any fancy OS actions. So getting the horse inside is the mistake, not getting killed afterwards.

Comment: How often do you compile TeX documents that you haven't written yourself?  I guess it could be hidden in a style file and put on CTAN, but it would still write the file when run just with `pdflatex` so it would be quite easy for people to spot without being in danger from it.  And once spotted, the package would get pulled from CTAN.  So on a scale from 1 to paranoid, I would rate this as "Theoretical but highly unlikely".

Comment: This behaviour is intended, as `arara` builds everything before running any command, so the first batch uses the original `pdflatex` rule. For the subsequent batches, the new rule will be used.

Comment: @AndrewStacey not often, but much more frequently then I run shell scripts from untrusted people without closely inspecting the file.